# Properties of object not shown in other objects

Tags: ios, xcode, properties, nsmanagedobject, nsobject

I have one very strange problem.

I create object DimensionItem :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Dimension;

@interface DimensionItem : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * dimItemID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Dimension *dimension;

@end
```

In some classes I can normaly access property ouf of it, but in some object when I create

```
DimensionItem * item = ...
item.name ---->  Property 'name' not found on object  of type 'DimensionItem'
```

I can't access to it and even autocorrect is off.

I include header in object :

```
#import "DimensionItem.h"
```

EDIT :

There was request for initialization code :

```
DimensionItem * item = [cubeItem getDimensionItemWhitDimensionID:self.dimensionID andDimensionItemID:[obj1 dimensionItemIndex]];
```

cubeitem is another NSManagedObject created which core data which has one-to-many relations with Dimension which has one-to-many relations with DimensionItem.

Function calculate position in set and return DimensionItem.

As I said, in some object this same function work with

```
item.name
```

but others don't

Comment: show me your code for the 'item' initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the properties of a `NSManagedObject` like that, it's not like a normal object. This is because the access to those properties should be managed by CoreData, not by you.

You need to use:

```
//Set
[item setValue:@"myName" forKey:@"name"];

//Get
[item valueForKey:@"name"]
```

Comment: But when Core Data populate the Object I can normally access those property. And normally I can. This is the first time that some objects (not all) don't give me those properti option

Comment: Yes, but no when you create it as a simple object

Comment: DimensionItems * item = ... gets object that Core Data create it. And how could xCode know when Core data create on object an when it is created as simple object? Moreover the same line of code DimensionItems * item = ...; item.name works in one object but not in the other.

Comment: There has to be any difference, hard to know without code. Whats the problem in accessing the values using the methods I wrote?

Comment: Nothing :D Thanks for that, but I am curious why is this happened. There is no difference in calling that function because it is the same function over the same object. And the working and nonworking object are both NSObjects